# Closing a file automatically in a Vivado simulation

Tags: verilog, simulation, vivado

I have a testbench that uses `$fopen` and `$fwrite` to write outputs. At the end of the simulation, the following code closes the files:

```
initial
  begin
     #10000 begin
        $fclose(file);
        $finish;
     end
  end
```

But what do I do if I want the simulation to run longer, or shorter? Can I somehow cause the files to be closed automatically when the simulation ends?

Comment: I saw that the file's content was truncated, so I assumed that was the cause.

Comment: Is part of a line truncated where you know the output terminates with a `\n`?  `$finish` isn't normally a C `exit()`.  Your simulator should gracefully close all open file handles.  For running the test longer, many methodologies essential create a semaphore and `$finish` is closed when the semaphore returns to zero.  A global semaphore can be hard to debug when you find out that the test is running infinitely, so you'd want to do more than just a bare semaphore to track which paths of the testbench are preventing the test from finishing.

Comment: It was actually truncated in the middle of a string. I thought the output might be buffered somewhere in the simulator.

Comment: I'll try the semaphore approach. It does sound more robust.

Comment: In general operating systems do buffer writes to files, to make your program run much more quickly.  Typically the disk blocks that make up a file are something like 4k bytes in size, and so the library buffers up smaller writes that you do until it has a full disk block, and then it writes that out all at once.  If you want to update the contents at particular points in the simulation (say the end of a test, so you can check on the results while the next test is running), you can insert a call to `$fflush(file);` at that point to make it write out the buffered up data.

Comment: @Mac good point. The problem here is that I was trying to use the simulator interactively and still get the buffered writes. I guess one solution is to flush after every write.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You shouldn't need to call `$fclose(file)` before you exit.

> By default, before the simulator terminates, all open files are closed. This means that the user does not have to close any files, and closing is done automatically by the simulator.

<strike>http://verilog.renerta.com/source/vrg00016.htm</strike> (source link no longer works)

Comment: Perhaps this isn't exactly the intended usage, but if I run the simulation interactively, and stop it (after all expected output has been written), I still see truncated files. Only if I close the interactive simulator or restart the simulation I see the missing parts of the files being written.